# Using jQuery to Clone nested divs with unique ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is cloning a div that looks like a row of many nested dropdowns, textareas, etc. (Note that the clone is appended to the html outside of this function). What I needed to do was to clone all of the html elements, rename the div and the first nested div to be unique, and occasionally keep all of the values.
The main div has a class of "divRow#" and the inner div that needs a unique name has a class of "innerDivRow#".

Is there a simpler way to do this? I couldn't get jQuery's clone to handle nested values and give the clone a unique ID.

```
function CreateCloneCriteria(original, keepValues) {
    var clone = $(original).clone();

    if (keepValues)
    {
        // unfortunately, the jquery library was unreliable for copying all of the children values correctly so we're doing it manually.
        $(clone).find('.form-control').each(function(){
            var cloneObject = this; // keep names straight
            var originalObject = $(original).find('#' + $(cloneObject).attr("id"));
            $(cloneObject).val($(originalObject).val());
        });
    }

    // give it a unique Id
    var maxIdNumber = 0;
    $('.divRow').each(function() {
        var thisIdSplit = $(this).attr("id").split("divRow");
        var thisIdNumber = parseInt(thisIdSplit[1]);
        if (thisIdNumber > maxIdNumber) {
            maxIdNumber = thisIdNumber;
        }
    })

    var newIdNumber = maxIdNumber + 1
    $(clone).attr("id", "divRow" + newIdNumber.toString());
    $(clone).children().first().attr("id", "innerDivRow" + newIdNumber.toString());

    return clone;
}
```

**The following is an explanation for why I had to do a bunch of manual work instead of just using jQuery's clone feature**

Update: I think the main problem I'm having with the jQuery deep nesting is that it's not moving over values that I've selected in dropdowns. Here's a jFiddle for an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/7de6c3co/3/

Comment: Did you try passing `true` for [deepWithDataAndEvents](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents)?

Comment: I tried deepWithDataAndEvents and it's like it isn't deep enough. I've got 3 layers going on and it doesn't copy the inner-most layer's data and events.

Comment: Alright- could you [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/180709/edit) your post to include the HTML? it can be pared down enough to show the layers necessary.

Comment: The html is really intense, but I think I found that the root issue was with select dropdowns, so I added an example of that.

Comment: "_I think the main problem I'm having with the jQuery deep nesting is that it's not moving over values that I've selected in dropdowns._" that is because there won't be any way in the HTML markup that signifies which option is _selected_. One could use Javascript to find the [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex).

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599828/1575353) for more information

Comment: @SamOnela Thank you for confirming my suspicions about that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues...

- ID's must always be unique, so when you clone an element with an ID you have to change the ID before putting it back in the DOM.
- You select box options read 1, 2, 3 but they all have a value of 1 so you wouldn't know it even they did change.
- After you clone the first row, all subsequent "clone" buttons will continue to clone the first row rather than the row from which the button was pressed, to fix that you must pass some context to the function  (`this`).
- Neither of the arguments for `$.clone()` have anything to do with persisting input values so yea, you'll have to do that manually.

In the re-write I've changed the markup as follows:

- Added a classname to the row, this allows you to easily determine how many rows you have via `$('.clonerow').length` and then use that number to generate unique IDs (eg: `clone.find('#divRow0').prop('id', 'divRow'+$('.clonerow').length);`
- Fixed the values for your dropdowns
- Passed `this` to your clone function.

```js
function Clone(clonebutton) {
  var row = $(clonebutton).parent(),
    inputVal = row.find('input').val(),
    selectVal = row.find('select').val(),
    original = $('#divRow0'),
    clone = $(original).clone(true, true);
  clone.find('#divRow0').prop('id', 'divRow' + $('.clonerow').length);
  clone.find('#innerDivRow0').prop('id', 'innerDivRow' + $('.clonerow').length);
  clone.find('input[type="text"]').val(inputVal);
  clone.find('select').val(selectVal);
  $('#container').append(clone);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="divRow0" class=clonerow>
    <div id="innerDivRow0">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Sample" />
      <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" onclick="Clone(this)" value="Clone" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet was answering a question about why I couldn't just use jQuery's clone without doing a bunch of work. I didn't intend for that to be diagnosed. Your 1st and 4th bullet points were the issues that caused me to code vomit in the first place. The initial code snippet is the working code I was asking to be reviewed. I'll update the post to make that more clear.

Comment: @Hannah - fair enough, i'm a lazy reader. that said, all of my advice is still applicable and relevant.